# C#, MEF - Sign trusted plugins for abuse reduction

Tags: c#, plugins, mef, signing

I have a program that is extendable by plugins using the Microsoft Extensibility Framework.
But i dont want untrusted sources to give out plugins that may be insecure.
So i want to sign the plugins (maybe with Visual Studio's built in signing) and check if the plugins are trustworthy at program start.

I didn't find a way to check DLL signing from inside C#. And also there is the problem, that I load the plugins with a DirectoryCatalog. There is no way to tell, which plugin is from which file. Anyone knows a way to do this?

Thanks for any help,
Marks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to use the DirectoryCatalog.  You will need to filter the assemblies yourself based on whether they are signed correctly.  You can iterate through the files in a directory, and call [AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyname.getassemblyname?view=net-5.0) for each one.  Then look at the [KeyPair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyname.keypair?view=net-5.0) property of the AssemblyName to determine whether the assembly is signed with a key you trust.  If it is, then create an [AssemblyCatalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.assemblycatalog?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) for that class and add it to an [AggregateCatalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.aggregatecatalog?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) which you will pass to the container.

Here is a blog post with an example of how to do this: [How To Control Who Can Write Extensions For Your MEF Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dsplaisted/how-to-control-who-can-write-extensions-for-your-mef-application)